# Is there any way to get table of contents of a man page?

Tags: bash, manpage

Some man pages are very big. I want firstly to see table of contents and then go to interesting section. How to do it?

For example:

```bsh
$ man -contents ls
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
AUTHOR
REPORTING BUGS
COPYRIGHT
SEE ALSO
```

Comment: It looks like all man pages have the same "table of content". So you got it already ;-)

Comment: Well, for example, tmux have not standard contents as “KEY BINDINGS”, “COMMANDS”, “CLIENTS AND SESSIONS” etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but I guess you could use `man -w` to locate the compressed troff source, and then search that for section headings (`.SH`)

Ex.

```
$ zcat "$(man -w ls)" | grep '^\.SH'
.SH NAME
.SH SYNOPSIS
.SH DESCRIPTION
.SH AUTHOR
.SH "REPORTING BUGS"
.SH COPYRIGHT
.SH "SEE ALSO"
```

Comment: Yes, is works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- run man as usual, which ought to run `less` to display the content, as evidenced by this kind of status line (at the bottom of the terminal window):

  ```
    Manual page man(1) line 1 (press h for help or q to quit)
  ```
- type `&^(   )?[^ ]` (with 3 spaces between the parentheses), then hit return, which should get you this:

  ```
    MAN(1)                        Manual pager utils                        MAN(1)
    NAME
    SYNOPSIS
    DESCRIPTION
    EXAMPLES
    OVERVIEW
    DEFAULTS
    OPTIONS
       General options
       Main modes of operation
       Finding manual pages
       Controlling formatted output
       Getting help
    EXIT STATUS
    ENVIRONMENT
    FILES
    SEE ALSO
    HISTORY
    2.8.3                             2018-04-05                            MAN(1)
  ```

  (bonus: with this method you get subsections as well)
- scroll so the section or subsection of interest sits in the first line. You might have to use shift-J to allow `less` to scroll the bottom of the screen beyond the end of file:

  ```
       Controlling formatted output
       Getting help
    EXIT STATUS
    ENVIRONMENT
    FILES
    SEE ALSO
    HISTORY
    2.8.3                             2018-04-05                            MAN(1)
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
  ```
- type `&`, then hit return, which should get you this:

  ```
       Controlling formatted output
           -P pager, --pager=pager
                  Specify which output pager to use.  By default, man uses  pager,
                  falling  back to cat if pager is not found or is not executable.
                  This option overrides the $MANPAGER environment variable,  which
                  in  turn  overrides  the $PAGER environment variable.  It is not
                  used in conjunction with -f or -k.

                  The value may be a simple command name or a command  with  argu‐
                  ments, and may use shell quoting (backslashes, single quotes, or
                  double quotes).  It may not use pipes to connect  multiple  com‐
                  mands;  if  you  need that, use a wrapper script, which may take
                  the file to display either as an argument or on standard input.

           -r prompt, --prompt=prompt
                  If a recent version of less is  used  as  the  pager,  man  will
                  attempt  to  set  its  prompt  and  some  sensible options.  The
                  default prompt looks like
  ```

  Note how the first line on screen remains the same.
- Browse the contents
- Repeat as necessary

Answer (score 0):

I have detected, that no all man pages have correct tags. (tmux .Sh instead .SH)
It modification is more universal: `zcat "$(man -w ls)" | grep '^\.[sS][hH]'`

Comment: You could suggest it to @steeldriver in comment of his answer

Comment: Just `grep -i '^\.sh'`